# Your file should validate and return its contents with `openssl smime -verify -inform DER -noverify`

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I uploaded an apple-association file to my server, which serves content over HTTPS but the link validator [here](https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com/) is giving me this error `Your file should validate and return its contents with openssl smime -verify -inform DER -noverify` I thought one doesn’t need to sign the file if targeting iOS 9? Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That validator is somewhat out of date. Give [this one](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/) a try instead.

Comment: Thanks. I used it and everything seems to be okay until I got more info using one provided by Apple here https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/  gives an error, based on the app's domain entitlement

Comment: That is the "App Search API Validation Tool", not the "Universal Links Validation Tool" (which doesn't exist from Apple). The results from this tool have no connection to whether Universal Links work or not

Comment: But does my app need to be on the store before Universal Links can start working, provided all things are okay in the validator you recommended?

Comment: No, it does not. Universal Links will actually work just fine on development builds, including in the simulator (as of iOS 10)